# Why does Chrome show the same 0x167F unicode character differently in 2 different places?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, unicode

My username: `ᔕᖺᘎᕊ` starts with the [0x167F unicode character](http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x1515/index.html) (CANADIAN SYLLABICS SHA).

Before I upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 7, I used to see this character as:

> [image: How I saw the character]

...**everywhere**.

However, after upgrading, I see it as the above image in the tab name (`<title>` attribute):

> [image: Vertical <code>S</code> looking letter]

...but on *actual pages* (on SE sites, Google, mail, etc...), I see it like:

> [image: Tilted <code>S</code> looking letter]

Now this (the last image) is apparently the *correct* display according to the *screnshot* at [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1515/index.htm).

---

Why is this (in my opinion weird) behaviour happening? And that too only in Windows 10 and not Windows 7? I would understand if it was different programs displaying this (I'd assume the program comes with its own 'font' that it uses), but the same character shown differently **in the same program** is what baffles me.

And is there any way to tell Chrome to display this character in one format only (either is fine by me!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're noticing the different fonts in use, so whilst the user interface uses one, the webpages have been styled with another. You might not have noticed this previously, as Windows can do a good job of font substitution where a font doesn't have a glyph for the character specified; now, the fonts have the character, so it is using those.

Comment: 2 questions: Why in only Windows 10? Any way to only see one of those 2 types?

Comment: Because the font(s) may have been updated with the OS (in a similar way to the way Segoe was between Windows 7 and 8). There may still be a limited set of fonts with the character, which may be why you're seeing so few variants.

Comment: Guess that makes sense (+1 :) - so I presume this means it isn't possible to 'fix' this??

Comment: There are a lot of font changes in Windows 10. For example for sometime they remove bitmaps from Japanese fonts and suddenly Japanese texts become elegantly beautiful, then for some reason they reverted that back in some RC versions and Japanese texts went back to the eye straining era